# Issue with Shared Element Transition Animation When Returning from Detail Page in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my application, when transitioning from a RecyclerView item to a detail page by clicking on it, I am successfully implementing the shared element transition animation. However, when I return (using onBackPressed or the back button), there is an issue with the items smoothly settling into place as they did during the animation.

I am successfully sharing the image and text elements from the detail page back to the RecyclerView, but there is a judder when the items settle into place upon returning. I am using postpone and start methods to ensure the animation completes.

Here are snippets of the code I am using:

**Transition from RecyclerView to the detail page:**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, ProductDetailsActivity:: class.java)
            intent.putExtra("product", product)

            val imagePair = Pair.create<View, String>(holder.binding.productsRowImg, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.binding.productsRowImg) ?: "")
            val productNamePair = Pair.create<View, String>(holder.binding.productsRowName, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.binding.productsRowName) ?: "")
            val productPricePair = Pair.create<View, String>(holder.binding.productsRowPrice, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.binding.productsRowPrice) ?: "")

            val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                context as Activity,
                imagePair,
                productNamePair,
                productPricePair
            )

            context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())

        }
```

**Starting the animation and placing the data on the detail page:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityProductDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val intent = intent
        val product = intent.getSerializableExtra("product") as Product

        setContents(product)

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun setContents(product: Product) {
        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this)

        // Put data
        Picasso.get().load(product.imageUrl).into(binding.productDetailsImg)
        binding.productNameTxt.text = product.productName
        binding.productPriceTxt.text = product.price.toString() + "TL"


        binding.productDetailsImg.let {
            it.doOnPreDraw {

                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(binding.productDetailsImg, "sharedProductImage")
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(binding.productNameTxt, "sharedProductName")
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(binding.productPriceTxt, "sharedProductPrice")

                ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(this)
            }
        }
```

How can I resolve this issue? Can you assist by providing relevant code snippets or screenshots? Thank you in advance.

When returning, I expected the animation to complete smoothly and the items to settle properly in their starting positions without a short jolt. However, I am experiencing this problem during the return animation and the items are experiencing some jitter.

Answer (score 0):

In the ProductDetailsActivity:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra("sharedProductImage", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(binding.productDetailsImg))
    intent.putExtra("sharedProductName", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(binding.productNameTxt))
    intent.putExtra("sharedProductPrice", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(binding.productPriceTxt))
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

In the RecyclerView activity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val sharedProductImageTransitionName = data?.getStringExtra("sharedProductImage")
        val sharedProductNameTransitionName = data?.getStringExtra("sharedProductName")
        val sharedProductPriceTransitionName = data?.getStringExtra("sharedProductPrice")

        // Assign transition names to RecyclerView items using the received transition names
        // Implement the animation to smoothly transition back to their original positions
    }
}
```

Replace YOUR_REQUEST_CODE with the appropriate request code used when starting the detail activity.